# How to union 2 querys in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have 2 querys.I want to union both querys.When am trying to add both querys not getting result.
Please find below 2 querys. Even i tried to add one single core PHP Query to in codeigniter model
But not getting result. can any one please help me on this query.

### Core PHP Based query in model codeigniter-method1

```
$sql = "select
                'Amadeus' AS SupplierName,TST_Type,TKT_Type,TKTNumber,TKT_FO_REF,BasePrice,TaxPrice,Commission1,BasePrice+TaxPrice AS TotalPrice,'issued' AS tkt_type,booking_price.CreatedBy as createdby,`TicketedDate` AS created_date,CONCAT(`a3m`.`firstname`,`a3m`.`lastname`) AS created_name,a3m.account_id,`a3m`.locationvalue AS Location_ID,`a3m`.locationdescription AS Location_Name,`a3m`.costcentervalue AS CostCenter_ID,`a3m`.costcenterdescription AS CostCenter_Name
                 from 
                 data_flight.booking_price
                 left join `a3m_account_details` `a3m` ON `a3m`.`account_id` = data_flight.booking_price.CreatedBy  
                 where TKTNumber!=''

                 union all

                 select 
                 'Amadeus' AS SupplierName,'' AS TST_Type,'' AS  TKT_Type,br_tkt AS TKTNumber,'' AS TKT_FO_REF,br_fare_paid_B AS BasePrice, br_tax_refund_TXT AS  TaxPrice,
                 br_cancellation_penalty AS Commission1, br_fare_total_RFT AS TotalPrice,br_cancel_type AS tkt_type,booking_refund.br_added_by AS createdby,br_refund_date AS created_date      ,CONCAT(`a3m`.`firstname`,`a3m`.`lastname`) AS created_name,a3m.account_id,`a3m`.locationvalue AS Location_ID,`a3m`.locationdescription AS Location_Name,`a3m`.costcentervalue AS CostCenter_ID,`a3m`.costcenterdescription AS CostCenter_Name
                from  
                 data_flight.booking_refund  
                left join `a3m_account_details` `a3m` ON `a3m`.`account_id` = data_flight.booking_refund.br_added_by
                where br_tkt!=''
                ";

        echo $this->db->query($sql);
```

### COdeigniter based query method2

```
$this->db->select('"Amadeus" AS SupplierName,TST_Type,TKT_Type,TKTNumber,TKT_FO_REF,BasePrice,TaxPrice,Commission1,(BasePrice+TaxPrice) AS TotalPrice,"issued" AS tkt_type,createdby,TicketedDate as created_date,CONCAT(a3m.firstname," ",a3m.lastname) AS created_name,a3m.account_id,a3m.locationvalue AS Location_ID,a3m.locationdescription AS Location_Name,a3m.costcentervalue AS CostCenter_ID,a3m.costcenterdescription AS CostCenter_Name');
        $this->db->from($this->traveldb->database.".booking_price bp");
        $this->db->join('a3m_account_details a3m','a3m.account_id=createdby','left');
        $this->db->where('TKTNumber !=', '');
        $query1 = $this->db->get(); 

         $this->db->select('"Amadeus" AS SupplierName,"" AS TST_Type,"" AS  TKT_Type,br_tkt AS TKTNumber,"" as TKT_FO_REF,br_fare_paid_B as BasePrice,br_tax_refund_TXT as TaxPrice,br_cancellation_penalty as Commission1,br_fare_total_RFT AS TotalPrice,br_cancel_type AS tkt_type,br_added_by as createdby,br_refund_date as created_date,CONCAT(a3m.firstname," ",a3m.lastname) AS created_name,a3m.account_id,a3m.locationvalue AS Location_ID,a3m.locationdescription AS Location_Name,a3m.costcentervalue AS CostCenter_ID,a3m.costcenterdescription AS CostCenter_Name');
        $this->db->from($this->traveldb->database.".booking_refund bp");
        $this->db->join('a3m_account_details a3m','a3m.account_id=br_added_by','left');
        $this->db->where('br_tkt !=', '');
        $query2 = $this->db->get(); 

        $query = $this->db->query($query1." UNION ".$query2); 

     echo $this->db->last_query();
```

I tried both methods in my model not getting result , tried to print query it showing erros. Please help me on this.

Comment: If you are using CodeIgniter 3 you can find the `get_compiled_select()` very interesting, because "Compiles the selection query just like $this->db->get() but does not run the query. This method simply returns the SQL query as a string.". If this is the case, you can then use `$query1 = $this->db->get_compiled_select(); [....] $query2 = $this->db->get_compiled_select(); $query = $this->db->query($query1." UNION ".$query2);` . Source: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html

Comment: Yes i tried but getting errors ,while union both querys in second query i have taken " " as TST_TYPE like that it showing error

Comment: After adding `get_compiled_select()` showing this error .. `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ALLSELECT `Amadeus` AS `SupplierName`, "" AS `TST_Type`, "" AS `TKT_Type`, `br_t' at line 4 `